# Running F# code with Mono

Tags: f#, mono

I have F# 2.0.0 installed, and use mono 2.8.

```
let rec fib n =
    match n with
    | 1 | 2 -> 1
    | n -> fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

let n = 40
let x = fib(n)
printfn "%d" x
```

I compiled this code with fsc.exe to get fib.exe. Running this with mono fib.exe gives me this error.

```
mono fact.exe 
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
'.$Factorial' from assembly 'factorial, Version=0.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

What might be wrong?

### ADDED

```
sudo gacutil -i FSharp.Core.dll
```

solved this problem.

Comment: Thanks! If you had compiled Mono 2.8 via http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/10/mono-2-8-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/ and used the install package for F# from here http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/ then the full command would be: sudo /opt/mono-2.8.2/bin/gacutil -i /usr/lib/fsharp/FSharp.Core.dll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The F# assemblies (like FSharp.Core.dll) are probably only installed to the .Net GAC.  You need to install them to Mono's GAC (Mono's gacutil.exe), or copy the assemblies into the same directory as your executable.