# Running F# exe on mono (mac)

Tags: f#, mono

I've installed Mono successfully with the [mac installer](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) (which includes F#), and have been playing around with the interactive shell. I can also compile F# source files just fine to produce a .NET EXE, but when I try to run it with Mono, I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type '<StartupCode$HelloWorld>.$HelloWorld' from assembly 'HelloWorld, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type '<StartupCode$HelloWorld>.$HelloWorld' from assembly 'HelloWorld, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The contents of the file — HelloWorld.fs — is simply

```
printfn "Hello world"
```

I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898650/running-f-code-with-mono), but the solution does not fix my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You should have `printfn` instead of `println` - to get the code to compile

Comment: Whoops, I made a typo in the post; fixing... Thanks for noticing that :)

Comment: I'm having no problem building that one-liner using fsc/fsc2 and running using mono 2.10.5 on my Macbook Pro. The other question seems like it just covers missing the FSharp assembly - not the problem you're having here.

Comment: Yeah, I can _build_ the file and get `HelloWorld.exe`, but it gives me the error when I try to run it with mono. I think my mono installation might be screwed up. :/

Comment: @Jwosty: Why don't you try with [Mono package release](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) which includes F# by default? The cross-platform package is quite obsolete and may not be compatible with recent Mono platform.

Comment: That's where I got the install from

Comment: @Jwosty: Then you don't need to install the cross-platform package. Why did you install it?

Comment: At the time, I didn't realize that F# already came with mono. I've also already tried uninstalling both then reinstalling just mono several time to no avail. Updating question...

Comment: I still really need this

Comment: This all seems very weird - you can run `fsi` and `fsc` which are compiled F# apps, but you can't run your own compiled stuff - can you run the compiled app under `strace` or the mac equivalent to see what syscalls fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had 2 different mono versions installed in two separate locations — 2.10.6 in `/opt/local/lib/mono` and 2.10.9 in `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework`. The `fsi` command was symlink to the `fsi.exe` that shipped with the latter, while the `mono` command itself was another symlink pointing to the former.

Lesson learned: Make sure you don't have two versions of the same software installed

Comment: The actual problem then would have been that the Fsharp libs were in one of the GACs but not the other - running `fsi/fsc` used the good GAC, but using `mono Helloworld.exe` would have run with the bad GAC

Comment: Oh, so I was basically having the same problem as the other question, only "halfway" :P