# F# on linux (mint/ubuntu) - dll path

Tags: linux, f#, mono

This is a similar question to [Running F# code with Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898650/running-f-code-with-mono) but the solution there doesn't work for me, and I suspect I've got a slightly different problem.

I'm on linux mint petra (based on ubuntu saucy) and I've installed `mono-complete` and `fsharp`. Running it doesn't work:

```
$ fsharpi
/home/me/unknown(1,1): error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'FSharp.Core.dll' in any of
  /usr/lib/mono/4.0
  /home/me
  /usr/lib/mono/4.0/
```

Which is not surprising, the file's in `/usr/lib/cli/FSharp.Core-4.3`. So let's try `gacutil`:

```
$ sudo gacutil -i /usr/lib/cli/FSharp.Core-4.3/FSharp.Core.dll
Installed /usr/lib/cli/FSharp.Core-4.3/FSharp.Core.dll into the gac (/usr/lib/mono/gac)
```

So `mono` and `gacutil` seem to disagree which paths to search! This is why I think I've got a different problem to the one referenced.

The command `MONO_PATH=/usr/lib/cli/FSharp.Core-4.3/ fsharpi` doesn't work either (it prints the same search paths as above).

How do I get F# up and running?

Comment: This should propbably be a bug report with linux mint.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu Saucy is at the end of life, so it is no longer supported. In Ubuntu 14.04 the `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/FSharp.Core.dll` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/cli/FSharp.Core-4.3/FSharp.Core.dll`. First check if all install jobs finished properly by running `apt-get install -f`. Then try to remove and reinstall the libfsharp-core4.3-cil package, e.g. with commands `apt-get remove libfsharp-core4.3-cil; apt-get install apt-get remove libfsharp-core4.3-cil`. You can create the symlinks manually, but they should be created automatically by the package install script.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm on mint/debian and I'm currently fighting the exact same issue...

Comment: Afraid not, I switched to windows for that project.